# How to delimit user input by a space

Tags: java, input, delimiter

I am trying to ask the user for two ints separated by a space. I also want to store the two separated numbers into two integer variables. Please help it is so simple I am having a hard time finding a good source for it.

```
System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
            String numbers = kb.nextLine();
            kb.useDelimiter(" ");
```

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `Scanner` to use the regex delimiter of `\\s+` which will remove all whitespace, or `\\s` if you want to remove a *single* space, but throw an `Exception` for any other input (such as two spaces in a row).

Additionally, ensure you call this method *before* you attempt to use `kb.next()`:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
kb.useDelimiter("\\s+");
System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
int valueOne = kb.nextInt();
int valueTwo = kb.nextInt();
System.out.println("Output: " + valueOne + " " + valueTwo);
```

You then individually can grab each input using `kb.nextInt()`, calling it as many times as you need, depending on how many values you want.

I suggest if you need a lot of values you instead call this from a `loop`, and not keep rewriting it.

**Trial Run:**

> Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): 5 6
>
> Output: 5 6

Note that this will only take in *integers* and throw an `InputMismatchException` if you attempt to use anything else.  You use `kb.next()` instead which will read a `String` if you want any value, then parse it into the type you need.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `useDelimiter`, since you've already read the line, you could `split` on space and convert each of those values to `int`s:

```
System.out.print("Please enter 2 integers (separated by spaces): ");
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String numbers = kb.nextLine();
String[] values = numbers.split(" ");
for(String value: values)
{
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(value));
}
```

Bear in mind that this will raise exceptions if non-numbers are provided as inputs.

Comment: Note that this will not read _two_ values, but every value on the line.  Entering `2 3 4 5 6` will give results for all 5 values which is not exactly the same thing.